# Using Azure private DNS zone with azure eventgrid

Tags: azure, dns

I'm trying to send event to a webhook with eventgrid to a private DNS adress.The Azure private DNS zone has been setup but the custom domain that is setup on the private DNS zone is not resolved. Is it possible to force eventgrid to use the private DNS zone?

The webhook events should be send to a private endpoint that is not accessible on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventGrid cannot resolve private DNS zones.

It is possible to use [EventGrid with Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/network-security#dns-changes-for-private-endpoints), but this allows your Virtual Network to send traffic to event grid via a private DNS zone.

If you have a custom DNS that you want Eventgrid to resolve, it have to be a public DNS zone.